# How to select all check boxes on facebook content library

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I have an old page with many posts/photos and I need to delete all posts/photos. I'm the creator of this page and. I need to select all checkboxes on this page.

I tried a few JS and jQuery codes in the console but it didn't work

Comment: How does selecting checkboxes help you delete something?  Can you show any code?

Comment: @jqueryHtmlCSS well, i tried to build a selenium python bot for click every checkboxes but  didn't click any checkboxes because classes are of list type.

Here are the codes of a checkbox:
`<button aria-checked="false" aria-disabled="false" aria-label="Satır Seç" class="_1gcq _29c- _1gco _5e9w" role="checkbox" type="button" style="border-color: rgb(190, 194, 201); background-color: transparent;"><i aria-hidden="true" class="_3w08 accessible_elem monochrome img sp_95MChtcHRzw sx_59a634" alt="" style="left: -2px; top: -2px;"></i></button>`

Comment: @jqueryHtmlCSS also this is the page https://prnt.sc/wmr65x

Answer (score -1):

Go to Facebook Creator Studio:  https://business.facebook.com/creatorstudio/content_posts

- Check first box of post you want to delete
- Hold down Shift
- Scroll vertical bar down to bottom of all posts
- Click last post checkbox with Shift key still held down.
- Click delete.